# How to view print statements from Resque Workers in terminal Ruby

Tags: ruby, resque

Using Redis and Resque to run background jobs. Currently trying to debug something that's going onto the queue. Problem is I cannot see the output of my print statements in terminal anywhere.

I tried to run workers with `tail -f` on the end, but getting rake errors each time I do that.

Anyone know how to view the output of Resque workers here?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? `I tried to run workers with tail -f on the end, but getting rake errors each time I do that.` What command are you using the run the workers? What rake error do you get? You should run `tail -f` on a log file, not a rake command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @Sachin you can use `Rails` logger ,

but `Resque` come up with own logging mechanism implemented over [`mono_logger`](https://github.com/steveklabnik/mono_logger)

you can also do

`Resque.logger.`[`info` | `warn` | `error` | `debug` | `fatal` ] are some of the log level feature that `Resque` Logging provide

Default Log is redirected to `STDOUT` (check [here](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/1-x-stable/lib/resque.rb#L474)) if you want to redirected to a file just change to a redirect it to a specific file in your code.

For more information on `mono_logger` refer the `github` [readme](https://github.com/steveklabnik/mono_logger/blob/master/README.md)

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

instead of using puts statement write to log with rails helpers

```
logger.debug "Person attributes hash: #{@person.attributes.inspect}"
logger.info "Processing the request..."
logger.fatal "Terminating application, raised unrecoverable error!!!"
```

you cannot see the result of puts statement and cant even use debugger in Resque.

Read about how to use logger in rails

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#sending-messages